# What was the name of the city which has sunk to the bottom of the sea?

Tags: futurama

There was a city in the US which has sunk to the bottom of the sea in the series. What was it's name? Why did it happen? In which episode did it happen?

Answer (score 4):

It was the city of Atlanta, Georgia. Just to note, Atlanta was most likely chosen because it's close to Atlantis, the lost city believed to have drowned, and the way they reveal the name on the sign suggests that. The city had long ago been separated and made into an island as a tourism move, but eventually began sinking as they continued developing on it and it became too heavy. Several very famous people chose to flee and the rest of its population chose to stay and live life underwater. The episode suggests that all the caffeine from the Coke factory sped up the evolution into the mermaid creatures they became.

The episode was named *The Deep South*, Season 2 Episode 12.

Answer (score 2):

It was the lost city of Atlanta. They cut it off from the main land many years ago and then it sank, since it was weighting too much to keep floating (Not that a floating island made any sense in the first place). 
The episode is called "The Deep South", from the second season. Favorite quote: "Realize it?? I don't even understand it!"